# Custom JSON array using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I use PHP to encode json data from my MySQL table, the output comes like this

```
[
    {
    "Copra_Crushed_MT": "2306.01851",
    "Oil_Extracted_MT": "1454.9442"
    },
    {
    "Copra_Crushed_MT": "1234",
    "Oil_Extracted_MT": "5678"
    },
    {
    "Copra_Crushed_MT": "1907",
    "Oil_Extracted_MT": "4605"
    }
 ]
```

But i want the structure to be this way, how should i proceed to get this

```
[
  [2306.01851,1454.9442],
  [1234,5678],
  [1907,4605]
]
```

my PHP code used to encode JSON

```
private function productionhourlys(){   
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $query="SELECT distinct c.Copra_Crushed_MT, c.Oil_Extracted_MT FROM productionhourlys c order by c.productionhourlyNumber desc";
        $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);

        if($r->num_rows > 0){
            $result = array();
            while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                $result[] = $row;
            }
            $this->response($this->json($result), 200); // send user details
        }
        $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
    }

private function json($data){
        if(is_array($data)){
            return json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `array_values` around your row:

```
$result[] = array_values($row);
```

([array_values docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php))

**Alternatively** (and probably the better way) - You can use `mysqli_result::fetch_row` instead of `fetch_assoc`

```
while($row = $r->fetch_row()) {
```

([fetch_row docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php))

`json_encode` in php will automatically turn associative arrays into json object (the curly brace syntax). You can use array values to remove keys and then `json_encode` will turn the arrays into JSON arrays (the square bracket syntax).

Comment: Thank you i made some progress. I get such an error,   `Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/content/52/10222452/html/e21designs/marico-IH/services/api.php on line 171`. I also get null at the start     `[null,["30/03/15","23.0069953"],["31/03/15","23434"],["30/03/15","23324"]]`